# Jenkins plugin for xunit to generate Jbehave reports

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jbehave

I am running Jbehave tests and wanted to view the Jbehave reports on Jenkins. I have installed xunit plugin on Jenkins as mentioned in http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/hudson-plugin.html . When I configure xunit test reports under the Post-build Actions of Jenkins job, I do not see the option for JBehave to add the report. xunit plugin installed is v 1.61. Can anyone tell me if I m doing something wrong or missing anything here?

Comment: Please can someone provide any assistance? Is it the problem with xuint plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so to see your jbehave tests in jenkins you need install on jenkins

1. xUnit jenkins plugin
2. Then install JBehave Hudson Plugin

   2.2 Read about it here
   http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/hudson-plugin.html

   2.3 Download hpi file (I use:
   jbehave-jenkins-plugin-3.7.4.hpi     Sat Nov 24 04:38:22 CST 2012    90030
   ) from:
   https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/releases/org/jbehave/jbehave-jenkins-plugin/3.7.4/

   2.4 Go to your jenkins to `pluginManager/advanced` and in section`Upload Plugin` ad downloaded file and upload it

   2.5 It should become visible in `pluginManager/available` section - so just check and install it.
3. Now navigate to your build to xUnit `Post-build Actions` and enjoy jbehave options

   3.1 Add directory where plugin should look for xml report like `**/jbehave/*.xml`

   3.2 If your jbehave is configured properly you should get all reports located in your workspace

If you need more help like configuring html view of jbehave reports, setting maven etc. make new question or update this one

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed process. I missed the hpi file step that caused all this.

Comment: Glad to help you - please give +1 to make this answer more valuable :)

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have to use xunit plugin to see the test reports.

There are other options available.

1. Make sure you have generate the required outputs (org.jbehave.core.reporters.XmlOutput). Then just publish the Junit test result.
2. Make sure you have generate the required outputs (HTML). Include

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jbehave.site</groupId>
       <artifactId>jbehave-site-resources</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.1</version>
       <type>zip</type>
   </dependency>
   ```

And you can publish as one of the HTML reports.